# crushing the app after throwing an error?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, backend

I don't know why when I Throw an new error when the api req doesn't has the info , the application crushed,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH6Bs.png)

But when I send a status with json , every thing done well [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5JKD.png)

I did every thing supposed to do , checking the postman requests and the db , but it didn't work with the "throw new Error('....')" ,
but it work with the json and retunr ..

I want to build a middleware for errorhandling but this issue stoped me

Answer (score 0):

When you use `throw new Error()`, you're throwing an error in your program, you're not sending an error message back to the client. Because this error isn't caught anywhere, it will crash your program. The way you showed in your second picture was correct. You're supposed to use the `.send()` method to send whatever data you want back to the sender.

`throw new Error()` is for when something happens on the server side, and the program cannot continue normally. If you're using code that throws errors, or you're writing code that does, you should add error handling in the form of a try/catch block.